# google apps script. How do i pass variables to a modal screen?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, client-server

I'm working on a google sheets add-on but i'm running into a problem. I want a pop up screen where users can make some selections. But i for the life of me can't find how to pass variables to this modal and how to get variables back to the main html file afterwards..

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('searchScreen').setWidth(400).setHeight(520), 'Select option');
```

Comment: There are two ways: `google.script.run`/template Search communication Html in the official documentation

Comment: Probably the best is [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).  It occurs before the page is loaded.